# Why is my SOAP variable hierarchy incorrect and how can I fix it?

Tags: xml, soap

I want to make the soap replay look like the example below:

```
 <IDAccountInquiryResult>
  <Success>true</Success>
  <Cost>1.00</Cost>
  <FailureMessage>Did not fail</FailureMessage>
 </IDAccountInquiryResult>
```

But I cannot get the outer level "IDAccountInquiryResult" to go through around the other variables  I currently only get the 3 variables in the middle

The code so far is below:

```
class IDAccountInquiryResult {
  public $InquirySuccess;
  public $CurrentBalance;
  public $FailureReason;
}

 $thisResponse = new IDAccountInquiryResult;
  $thisResponse->InquirySuccess = true;
  $thisResponse->CurrentBalance = "1.00";
  $thisResponse->FailureReason = "Success";
return $thisResponse;
```